# Fullcalendar scheduler's labels in error in 2017

Tags: label, fullcalendar, scheduler

I'm using fullcalendar's scheduler plugin version **1.0.0**

I'm in a J2EE environment.

We use the calendar in french language and the first day of week is monday. It works perfectly fine in 2016 but strangly in 2017 the labels are wrong. Because a picture describes it better, here it is :

[Here it works fine, first day is monday (Lundi)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HU8eG.png)

[But here, the label is saturday (Samedi)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaHPf.png)

And it continues during all the year with this mistake. How to resolve this issue ?

Here is a part of the fullcalendar configuration we use :

```
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
            lang: 'fr',
            firstDay: 1,
            aspectRatio: 2.3,
            scrollTime: '00:00',
            allDaySlot: false,
            weekNumbers: true,
            defaultDate: getDateDuJour(),
            selectable: true,
            resourceAreaWidth: "20%",
            eventOverlap: true,
            // Pour déclencher un passage dans "events" lors d'un changement de mode de vue (jour, semaine...)
            lazyFetching: false,
            header: {
                left: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'timelineMonth, timelineDay,timelineWeek,agendaWeek'
            },
            defaultView: '#{controleur.planningCollectifDelegate.vue}',
            views: {
                timelineWeek: {
                    slotDuration: '01:00',
                    minTime: '09:00',
                    maxTime: '18:00',
                    hiddenDays: [0, 6],
                },
                agendaWeek: {
                    buttonText: 'Agenda',
                    height: 200,
                    slotDuration: '00:30',
                    minTime: '09:00',
                    maxTime: '18:00',
                    hiddenDays: [0, 6],
                },
                timelineDay: {
                    slotDuration: '00:30',
                    minTime: '08:00',
                    maxTime: '22:00',
                    hiddenDays: [0],
                }
            },
            resourceColumns: [
            {
                labelText: 'Personnes',
                field: 'title'
            }],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE :

I have, by mistake and I don't understand why or how, resolved my problem. The source comes from the **moment.js** file in version **2.9.0**

Here are the lines I modified (in comment the original)

```
_weekdays: "Sunday_Monday_Tuesday_Wednesday_Thursday_Friday_Saturday".split("_"),
    /*weekdays: function(a) {
        return this._weekdays[a.day()]
    },*/
    _weekdaysShort: "Sun_Mon_Tue_Wed_Thu_Fri_Sat".split("_"),
    weekdaysShort: function(a) {
        //return this._weekdaysShort[a.day()]
        return this._weekdays[a.day()]
    },
    _weekdaysMin: "Su_Mo_Tu_We_Th_Fr_Sa".split("_"),
    weekdaysMin: function(a) {
        return this._weekdaysMin[a.day()]
    },
    weekdaysParse: function(a) {
        var b, c, d;
        for (this._weekdaysParse || (this._weekdaysParse = []), b = 0; 7 > b; b++)
            if (this._weekdaysParse[b] || (c = vb([2e3, 1]).day(b), d = "^" + this.weekdays(c, "") + "|^" + this.weekdaysShort(c, "") + "|^" + this.weekdaysMin(c, ""), this._weekdaysParse[b] = new RegExp(d.replace(".", ""), "i")), this._weekdaysParse[b].test(a)) return b
    },
```

It generate a javascript error each time I change view in fullcalendar but the labels of days are good.

Can someone explain why and if there is another work around to achieve my goal ?

Thank's